# Moving animation from Java to XML is inconsistent

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have an animation that I wrote using Java and would like to move it to an xml resource. However, the end result of the image is slightly larger and does not return to it's normal size when using a resource animation.

I've tried using percentages for scale but that results in a much larger size... I'm banging my head here.

Java animation

```
public void animateClickView(final ImageView view) {
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.2f, 0.0f, 1.2f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    animation.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    animation.setDuration(300);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1.3f, 1.0f, 1.3f, 1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            scaleAnimation.setDuration(250);
            view.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });

    view.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Resource animation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:shareInterpolator="true"
    android:duration="300">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <scale
        android:startOffset="301"
        android:fromXScale="1.2"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, your two Java animations cannot be translated into a **single** XML animation because they are different in their settings (for example one calls `setFillAfter(true)` and one doesn't). Rather you will have to have as many XML animations as you have Java animations and you will have to connect these animations in the same fashion as you connect the Java animations - through a listener.

So you have two XML animations, called `anim1` and `anim2`. Here is `anim1`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="300"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2" />

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

And here is `anim2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.3"
        android:fromYScale="1.3"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

And you will connect them in Java like this:

```
Animation animation1;
animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.anim1);
animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        Animation animation2;
        animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                        R.anim.anim2);
        view.startAnimation(animation2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
});
view.startAnimation(animation1);
```